# How is this helper working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Models:

```
 Group:
 has_many :booth_marketing_messages, :dependent => :destroy

 Booth Marketing Message:
 belongs_to :group
```

Routes:

```
   resources :groups do
      member do
       get :get_group_links
        get :booth_marketing_messages
       end
      resources :booth_marketing_messages do
         member do
           match :toggle_activation
         end
      end
    end
```

For creating a new booth marketing message I have a view with:

```
 <% form_for :asset, :url => (defined?(msg) ? group_booth_marketing_message_path(msg) :        
       group_booth_marketing_messages_path), :html => { :multipart => true, :method => 
      (defined?(msg) && msg ? :put : :post) } do |f| -%>
             .......
```

When I run rake routes:

```
     booth_marketing_messages_group GET  /groups/:id/booth_marketing_messages(.:format)                                        
     {:action=>"booth_marketing_messages", :controller=>"groups"}

      group_booth_marketing_messages GET 
     /groups/:group_id/booth_marketing_messages(.:format)                                  
     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"booth_marketing_messages"}
```

But my booth marketing message controller does not have an index action. Yes this route does not fail, how is that?

Answer (score 1):

You have written routes as

```
resources :booth_marketing_messages do
     member do
       match :toggle_activation
     end
  end
```

So it will create basic routes as index, new, create, update, destroy, edit and show regardless of there is any action mentioned in controller or even if there is no controller.

But when you go to that url you will get error of action not found or controller is not present.

So if you want to avoid or dont want to use the default routes you can use only and except in routes
eg.

```
resources :products, only: [:new]
```

This will create route for only new action and

```
resources :products, except: [:new]
```

This will create all routes except for new action

Hope this makes you clear

Comment: I understand what you are sayign but "But when you go to that url you will get error of action not found or controller is not present." - thats the thing, I DONT have an index action/index view for BoothMarketingMessagesController but the url I mentioned in the form in the 'new' action is not throwing any error...I wanted to know why it was NOT throwing an error?

Comment: Means if you enter that url in browser u are not getting any error like "Unknown action"?
So instead what u getting? any page ?

Comment: Yes it is not throwing any error but is instead routed to booth_marketing_messages_group_path

Comment: booth_marketing_messages_group GET    /groups/:id/booth_marketing_messages

group_booth_marketing_messages GET    /groups/:group_id/booth_marketing_messages


You have two routes conflicting, both are giving same url. You should be changing the routes. Dont use any action having same name as nested resource else try :path for route if they are same name

Comment: But when I run rake routes the paths seem to be different ie : booth_marketing_messages_group_path and group_booth_marketing_messages_path so how can they conflict?

Comment: the route helper method are different but the url they are giving are same
 /groups/:id/booth_marketing_messages